# Is it possible to make Graphics plot portable like ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to make a base Graphics-library plot portable in the same way that ggplot plots are portable?  That is, you can pass the plot to various functions and call print(plot) without encountering an error.

Comment: As Josh says, base graphics isn't really designed for this. However, you could give the lattice plots a try; they do return objects which can be manipulated and passed around.

Comment: The issue is not with plots that I create myself (I use ggplot), but with plots that are created by various libraries on CRAN.  These functions are incredibly useful, but unfortunately implimented using Graphics and not ggplot nor lattice

Comment: In that case, the best approach would be as follows. Rather than create the plot and then try to modify it, get the code used to generate the plot and modify that, then run it to make the new plot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pair of functions `recordPlot()` and `replayPlot()` do something similar to, but not *exactly* like this. One difference is that, unlike with `ggplot2` and `lattice` graphics, the figure must be first plotted to a graphics device before it is recorded.

```
# Plot and then record a figure
plot(rnorm(99))
recPlot <- recordPlot()
dev.off()

# Plot recorded figure to default graphics device
replayPlot(recPlot)

# Plot recorded figure to the pdf graphics device
pdf("eg.pdf")
replayPlot(recPlot)
dev.off()

# Look at the data structure that stores the plot
str(rPlot)
```

Comment: Very cool!  Is there an easy mechanism to apply a "theme" after recording the plot?  For example, lets say I wanted to change the font for the plot after recording/capturing it.

Comment: My strong impression/recollection is that no, there is not.  I'll be interested if anyone chimes in with contradictory info, because it would be nice.  But I think these functions simply weren't designed with that kind of use in mind, the typical advice being to save and edit the textual source instead.