# How to save boxplot to as to a variable?

Tags: r, boxplot

How can I save the box plot as a variable in R?
For example, if I did like this,

```
plot <- boxplot(count ~ spray, data = InsectSprays, col = "lightgray")
```

when I call plot, I want it shows the box plot, that I don't need to run the command for plotting boxplot every time.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: You could try using ggplot2.

Comment: `bxp(plot)`.. (you can't) or `plot <- function() boxplot(count ~ spray, data = InsectSprays, col = "lightgray"); plot()` if you want to be silly

Comment: Just a side note: might be better to choose a different name than `plot` for your variable since `plot` is also a function (to avoid confusion mainly)

Comment: @rawr, wouldn't that overwrite the normal `plot()` function? (just use `myplot <- function() .. ` instead to avoid overwriting)

Comment: @beginneR it sure would

Comment: See [**Is it possible to make Graphics plot portable like ggplot?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482960/is-it-possible-to-make-graphics-plot-portable-like-ggplot)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following does it. Call after that recordedPlot

```
boxplot(count ~ spray, data = InsectSprays, col = "lightgray")
recordedPlot = recordPlot()
dev.off()
```

Comment: I get: 
plot(recordedPlot)
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'