# Why does Boxplot appear in RStudio instead of my Shiny app?

Tags: r, plot, shiny

I have the following code. Three plots (1st, 2nd, 4th) are properly displayed in my Shiny app, whereas the 3rd one, which is the "boxplot", is missing. However it appears in RStudio's Plot window. What am I doing wrong?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

    fluidRow( 
        verticalLayout( 
            splitLayout(cellWidths = c("50%", "50%"), 
                        plotOutput("pt1"), 
                        plotOutput("pt2")), 
            splitLayout(cellWidths = c("50%", "50%"), 
                        plotOutput("pt3"), 
                        plotOutput("pt4"))
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    set.seed(1234)

    pt1 <- qplot(rnorm(600),fill=I("blue"),binwidth=0.2)
    pt2 <- qplot(rnorm(200),fill=I("blue"),binwidth=0.2)
    pt3 <- boxplot(mpg~cyl,data=mtcars, main="Cars", xlab="cyl", ylab="mpg") 
    pt4 <- qplot(rnorm(900),fill=I("blue"),binwidth=0.2)

    output$pt1 = renderPlot({pt1})
    output$pt2 = renderPlot({pt2})
    output$pt3 = renderPlot({pt3})
    output$pt4 = renderPlot({pt4})    

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see here: [How to save boxplot to as to a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27064296/how-to-save-boxplot-to-as-to-a-variable) we need a little trick to save a boxplot as a variable.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
ui <- fluidPage(

  fluidRow( 
    verticalLayout( 
      splitLayout(cellWidths = c("50%", "50%"), 
                  plotOutput("pt1"), 
                  plotOutput("pt2")), 
      splitLayout(cellWidths = c("50%", "50%"), 
                  plotOutput("pt3"), 
                  plotOutput("pt4"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  set.seed(1234)

  pt1 <- qplot(rnorm(600),fill=I("blue"),binwidth=0.2)
  pt2 <- qplot(rnorm(200),fill=I("blue"),binwidth=0.2)
  boxplot(mpg~cyl,data=mtcars, main="Cars", xlab="cyl", ylab="mpg")
  pt3 = recordPlot()
  dev.off()

  pt4 <- qplot(rnorm(900),fill=I("blue"),binwidth=0.2)

  output$pt1 = renderPlot({pt1})
  output$pt2 = renderPlot({pt2})
  output$pt3 = renderPlot({pt3 })
  output$pt4 = renderPlot({pt4})    

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```