# How to create boxplot from boxplot list in R

Tags: r, boxplot

Suppose, I do not have my original vector v from which to plot `boxplot(v)`but only the boxplot list object l as from `l <- boxplot(v)`. How do I recreate the boxplot plot from l? `boxplot(l)`obviously does not work and I also don't want to rebuild a boxplot from scratch in ggplot.

Thank you for your help!

Example

```
set.seed(3)
v <- rchisq(1:100000,df = 10)
boxplot(v)
l <- boxplot(v)
str(l)
boxplot(l) #Error in x[floor(d)] + x[ceiling(d)] : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27064296/how-to-save-boxplot-to-as-to-a-variable/27064701) from an older post. In the comments, they point out the bxp function.

```
set.seed(3)
v <- rchisq(1:100000,df = 10)
boxplot(v)
l <- boxplot(v)
dev.off()
bxp(l)
```

Also, don't knock ggplot! It is the way.

Answer (score 0):

```
set.seed(3)
v <- rchisq(1:100000,df = 10)

boxplot(v)
l <- recordPlot()
replayPlot(l)
```